# Get details of user administered pages in facebook using fb.api method

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-page

```
        function Pages()
        {
            FB.api(
'/me/accounts',
'GET',
{ fields: 'name,about' },
function(response) {        
    document.getElementById('showPages').innerHTML = response.name + ' ' + response.about ; 
},{ scope: 'manage_pages' }
);
     }
```

I'm using this function to get the name and about the pages administered by the user who has logged-in into my application.

I'm getting the output as "undefined".

Comment: FB.api does not ask for permissions, trying to pass a `scope` to it is nonsense. Asking for permissions is what FB.login does. And the response object for this API call (when successful) is not structured like you think it is - so log it to console to inspect and understand it.

Comment: in console i m getting
response=Object {data: Array[0]}

and i have done removing the scope also .. even then i was getting the same output.

Comment: read this: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: You still need to ask the user for the permission.

Comment: @CBroe Can u plz tell me how to ask ... i am new to development and i m finding the graph api documentation very confusing.. Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0):

It worked .. 
GET had to be removed..

Answer (score -1):

Try  `FB.api('/me/applications/developer',` 
instead of `FB.api('/me/accounts')`

May be that works.

Comment: Even I've the same error , it did not work for me either

Comment: y did u tell me then ?

Comment: I thought if it worked for you , I can ask what's  the problem with mine.

Comment: he wants the pages, not apps or app developers

Comment: thank u ! .. u can bookmark the question for further reference .. 

what was the error u were getting ???